# invers image topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider topological spaces $(X, \tau_{X}), (Y, \tau_{Y})$ and a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Define $f^{-1}\tau:=\{f^{-1}(\theta):\theta \in \tau\}$. Prove that $f^{-1}\tau_{Y}$ is a topology.

So, as $\tau_{Y}$ is a topology, than $\emptyset \in \tau_Y$. From the definition of image, I obtain that $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. Hence $f^{-1}(f(\emptyset))=f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, so $\emptyset\in f^{-1}\tau_Y$.

Naturally, $Y\in \tau_{Y}$. Since $f^{-1}(Y)=X$, $X\in f^{-1}\tau_Y$.

Now it is time for the  union. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a family of sets form $f^{-1}\tau_Y$. It means that for every $A\in \mathcal{A}$ there exists $\theta\in \tau_Y$ such that $f^{-1}(\theta)=A$. Consider
$f^{-1}(\bigcup \mathcal{A})=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{s\in S}A_{s})=\bigcup_{s\in S}f^{-1}(A_{s})=\bigcup_{s \in S}\theta_{s}$. 
Hence $\mathcal{A}\subset f^{-1}\tau_Y$.

The last part is the intersection. Pick $A_{1}, A_{2}$ from $f^{-1}\tau_Y$. There exist $\theta_1, \theta_2\in \tau_y$ such that $f^{-1}(\theta_i)=A_i, i=1,2$. Consider $f^{-1}(\theta_1 \cap \theta_2)=f^{-1}(\theta_{1})\cap f^{-1}(\theta_{2})=A_1\cap A_{2}$, hence the intersection belongs to $f^{-1}\tau_Y$ and it ends the proof. Do you find it correct? Actually, I don't need to consider topological space $(X, \tau_X)$, $X$ itself is enough.

Comment: It looks like you changed your mind about notations on $\mathcal{A}$ in the middle of the union portion, but otherwise good.

Comment: Indeed it is true.

Comment: Im not sure about one thing - the inverse image property for any union. To be exact is the following statement true? $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{s \in S} A_{s})=\bigcup_{s\in S}f^{-1}(A_{s})$ ?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the very begining. Note that $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=f^{-1}(f(\emptyset))\supset \emptyset$ and we get what we need too.

Comment: Yes, in general $f^{-1} (f(S)) \neq S$ unless $f$ is an injection. But it's still easy enough to see $f^{-1}( \emptyset ) = \emptyset$.